# Matlab use integration result within solver function

Tags: matlab

I want to integrate a system defined by several ODE's. My problem is, that I need a value, obtained some integration steps before.

Imagine you have a funtion y'=f(x,y(t-dt)).
That's a system with a time delay.

So in the k'th integration step I need the value of the j'th integration step. So when I execute integration step k I need access to the solver results y(1,...,k-1). Is that possible in MATLAB? And when yes, how could I do this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an ODE, but maybe rather a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) (DDE)? For Matlab, [see here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/delay-differential-equations.html).

Comment: can you just put them in a separate variable

Comment: the problem is, that the deley is not constant in the integration argument (in my examle above, dt is a function of t dt(t)). So I think Matlabs DDE won't work...